# How to store longitude and latitude in database. MySQL won't go further than -99.9999999

Tags: mysql, database, decimal, sqldatatypes

Ok right now I'm storing lat and lng columns as `DECIMAL(10,8)`

I'm trying to insert this:

`-117.1779216` However it keeps inserting as this : `-99.99999999`

Why is this? I see every other board storing it as DECIMAL, but it won't go back more when I'm giving it 10 places before the period... So I would think it could go -117.. None of them are marked as `unsigned` either.

Comment: [Read the manual.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: .. ? That doesn't help. Every other board stores it as this and it seems to work so I'm confused on why mine doesn't..

Comment: Reading doesn't help? If you read it the you would know you need to increase the precision.

Comment: No, I think you'll find they don't store it as DECIMAL(10, 8)... precisely because of the issue you're running into.

Comment: Ok well whatever. You guys didn't help. But I found an answer (11,8) instead of (10,8) Not sure why, but found it.

Comment: @AMR Store as a string? If you do, make sure it's not ASCII - I've heard EBDIC is the next big thing

Comment: In all seriousness @AMR I'm not sure if that was a joke comment or not but you should remove that comment in case someone takes it seriously.

Comment: @Zane I think they should leave it, in case the OP takes it literally. In which case the world will be a better place.

Comment: And from MySQL 5.0, [DECIMAL values are stored in binary format. Previously, they were stored as strings, with one character used for each digit of the value...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html) Also, @Peanut, read my answer.

Comment: @AMR not if you wish to perform and mathematics using those numbers.

Comment: @AMR what do you mean limited numerical options in SQL DECIMAL works perfectly. You should not store numeric values as strings it at best incredibly limiting on what can be done with those values.

Comment: @AMR common sense does not dictate that. What if it makes sense to do at the database level. What if you need to search for a row by using the LON and LAT?!

Comment: @AMR storing numeric data in a string is almost always a poor idea.

Answer (score 14):

[image]

Precision (10) - Scale (8) = 2

2 is the number of digits you can have to the left of the decimal

If you increase the precision, you can have more digits to the left of the decimal.

[image]

Comment: Maybe you do have to point out how this increasing of the scale works? :)

Comment: You got 5+ upvotes solely because of Kermit the Frog.

Comment: @NobleUplift I've been waiting to use him.

Comment: He's definitely something I never, ever expected to see on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 7):

The declaration syntax for a DECIMAL column is DECIMAL(M,D). The ranges of values for the arguments in MySQL 5.1 are as follows:

M is the maximum number of digits (the precision). It has a range of 1 to 65. (Older versions of MySQL permitted a range of 1 to 254.)

D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale). It has a range of 0 to 30 and must be no larger than M.

Taken from the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/precision-math-decimal-changes.html)  :D

Comment: Yes I see that... Not sure how that helps. (11,8) did it for longitude while (10,8) is good for latitude

Comment: Hope the OP reads your answer since they're incapable of reading the manual from which your answer came from.

Comment: Seriously? Your number of digits is greater than the allowed decimal, so it fills out the lowest value it can take.

Comment: @veelen Don't bother. Just hope you never have to work with that individual.

Comment: @veelen How's life in the Netherlands?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO https://www.google.nl/search?q=wheater+netherlands&oq=wheater+netherlands&aqs=chrome..69i57.5055j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @veelen Have me beat by 9 degrees.

Answer (score 2):

You set it to `DECIMAL(10,8)` with the number `-117.1779216`. MySQL reads this as `-117.17792160` because it needs 8 digits of precision, but you said it should only have 10 digits, so anything over 99 makes it 11 digits and invalid.