# phpmyadmin table values over 100 get changed to 99.99999999

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin

I am importing a table into a phpmyadmin database as a .CSV file, the file has some values within it which are greater than 100 for example 284.543536, 694.5435432, etc... When I import the file all values under 100 get imported fine and show on the table as expected however, the values over 100 get changed to 99.99999999. I have tried to find a solution for this but am struggling, could someone please explain to me why this keeps happening.

Comment: Show us the data type for that column. I suspect it is `decimal(n+2,n)`

Comment: the data type is automatically set to decimal(10,8)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20548800/how-to-store-longitude-and-latitude-in-database-mysql-wont-go-further-than-99

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is set to only allow two decimal places before the dot causing your values to be truncated. You will need to change it to allow higher numbers. `decimal(10,7)` would solve this issue for the numbers you have used in your example but if you plan on getting values over 1000 you will need to adjust this further.

Comment: I changed this but it just changes the value from 99.99999 to 100, is there any way of doing this during the import?

Comment: You have to set that column up first with the right data type then do your import.